# How do I use RoboUnitTestCase?

Tags: java, android, roboguice

I'm trying to follow the (official, I think) guide to RoboGuice on https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/Testing, but I can't figure out the first example. It seems to use a class called roboguice.test.RoboUnitTestCase so it can call getContext(), which I need to do. My class isn't an Activity - it just uses the Context to parse application info in its constructor.

The problem is that there doesn't seem to be a roboguice.test package anymore. What should I subclass instead? Does my testing class need to extend anything in the first place?

I'm using Android Studio 1.2 Beta, Gradle 1.1.0, JUnit 4, and RoboGuice 3.

Comment: Well, I've found https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/issues/118 - apparently the class was deprecated sometime before 2013. Of course, that doesn't explain why the documentation is now *four years* out of date.